# Exclude category from foreach loop

Tags: categories, exclude, php

How can I exclude one category from this loop wher I list my custom type projects by year ?

```
<?php foreach(posts_by_year() as $year => $posts) : ?>
  <h3><?php echo $year; ?></h3>

  <ul>
    <?php foreach($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
      <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4"><hr class="et_pb_space et_pb_divider"style="border-color: #f7f7f9;"></div>
  </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

update, the function :

```
function posts_by_year() {
  // array to use for results
  $years = array();

  // get posts from WP
  $posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category' => -27
  ));

  // loop through posts, populating $years arrays
  foreach($posts as $post) {
    $years[date('Y', strtotime($post->post_date))][] = $post;
  }

  // reverse sort by year
  krsort($years);
  return $years;
}
```

Comment: You need to write filtering code in the function `posts_by_year`. Only after filtering you need to return output from the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using the following code from [this pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/3EqY0NiH)

```
function posts_by_year() {
  // array to use for results
  $years = array();
 
  // get posts from WP
  $posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'my-custom-post-type',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
  ));
 
  // loop through posts, populating $years arrays
  foreach($posts as $post) {
    $years[date('Y', strtotime($post->post_date))][] = $post;
  }
 
  // reverse sort by year
  krsort($years);
  return $years;
}
```

This function uses [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to return the list of posts. To exclude a category, you can pass the `category` parameter to your arguments. Just one note

> **Note:** The category parameter needs to be the ID of the category, and not the category name.
>
> **Note:** The category parameter can be a comma separated list of categories, as the `get_posts()` function passes the 'category' parameter directly into `WP_Query` as `cat`.

**EDIT**

Please note, to exclude a category, you need to use the minus (`-`) sign in front of the category ID. Something like this will do. Just change `-13` to the `-ID` where ID is the ID of the category you want to exclude

```
function posts_by_year() {
  // array to use for results
  $years = array();
 
  // get posts from WP
  $posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'my-custom-post-type',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category' => -13
  ));
 
  // loop through posts, populating $years arrays
  foreach($posts as $post) {
    $years[date('Y', strtotime($post->post_date))][] = $post;
  }
 
  // reverse sort by year
  krsort($years);
  return $years;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Copy and paste this code as is. You had a syntax error, that is why you got the blank page

```
function posts_by_year() {
  // array to use for results
  $years = array();

  // get posts from WP
  $posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'project', 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category' => -27
  ));

  // loop through posts, populating $years arrays
  foreach($posts as $post) {
    $years[date('Y', strtotime($post->post_date))][] = $post;
  }

  // reverse sort by year
  krsort($years);
  return $years;
}
```

**EDIT 3**

It seems that you are making use of a custom taxonomy. If this is the case, make use of `tax_query` For available parameters, see [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). You just need to add the name of your taxonomy in the `taxonomy` parameter

```
function posts_by_year() {
  // array to use for results
  $years = array();

  // get posts from WP
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'project', 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'NAME OF YOUR CUSTOM TAXONOMY',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => '27',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ),
    ),
  ));

  // loop through posts, populating $years arrays
  foreach($posts as $post) {
    $years[date('Y', strtotime($post->post_date))][] = $post;
  }

  // reverse sort by year
  krsort($years);
  return $years;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! That is the function I am using. I will try. Don t know how to pass the category, somthing like : $args = array(  'exclude' => '27' );  ? (this doesn't work)

Comment: See my update, :-)

Comment: Thank you very much but it is not working ! blank page...

Comment: Just updated my first post, post from category 27 are still displaying

Comment: Thank you, no blank page but still posts from cat 27 !

Comment: Are you using build in categories or a custom taxonomy, your code works fine, it can only fail if you are using a custom taxonomy

Comment: It is a custom category of my custom post "project" from divi theme.

Comment: sorry, custom taxonomy, registred by the theme.

Comment: Yes !! Thank you very much for the time spent here to help me. :)

Comment: It was a pleasure, glad we could solve your problem :-) Enjoy